# Why does x[y] == y[x] in c++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

Someone told me this... I didn't believe them at first but it does work. If x and y do not change throughout the code, why does this work:

```
int x [5] = { 0,1,2,3,4};
int y = 3;

if(x[y] == y[x]){
    cout << "Why..." << endl;
}
```

How does x array's value in index y is = the x index's value's in array y? But there was no y array.

Comment: This has been asked and answered gazillion times in various FAQs as well as here, on SO. C FAQ link: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html

Answer (score 6):

It is always true (for normal operator==)

```
a[i]  --> *(a+i) --> *(i+a) --> i[a]
```

since int is intrinsic and has commutative operator==, this will always be true

Comment: @delnan: How was that not the question?  Both expressions are pointer dereference of the same pointer addition.

Comment: More importantly, because `int*` doesn't have an overloaded `operator[]`!

Answer (score 3):

Because all of the following are same:

```
x[y] == y[x] == *(x+y) == *(y+x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `x[y]` is just another way to say `*(x + y)`, and that is the same as `*(y + x)`.

Comment: You mean "...another way to say `*(x + y)`, and that is the same as `*(y + x)`.

Comment: No, it's saying `*(x + y)`. `&x[y]` would be saying `x + y`.